# How to properly serialize auto generated WCF types

Tags: c#, wcf, events, serialization, reflection

I'm using a WCF service with an code, which was generated from a mex endpoint.

I would like to be able serialize the classes, which were automatically generated.

My problem is, that those auto-generated classes implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and occasionally when serializing them, I'm getting following exception:

```
Type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager' in 
Assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
```

Normally I would deal with this exception by adding `[NonSerializable]` to the `PropertyChanged` event, but here the code is auto-generated, and I don't want to change it.

What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: which serializer are you using here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `BinaryFormatter` - however, WCF types are intended for serialization with `DataContractSerializer`, or related serializers (`NetDataContractSerializer`, protobuf-net, etc). Try using `DataContractSerializer` instead - your problem should evaporate.

Comment: @Arsen if "it" = `DataContractSerializer` - kinda, but not very well. Actually, there's nothing "conventional" about `[Serializable]` - BF is just one of many - it is not a special/default case.